# flutter_map marker movement

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

I'm using flutter_map to show map and some vehicles within marker layer.
I get update with their position coordinates every 5 seconds. Is there any way to animate vehicle movement between this coordinate change, instead of "teleporting" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround was made by generating coordinates in between those that need to be animated, and then simply looping and drawing them every 50ms for 5 seconds.